# MSON-React UI code generator support for other backends

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, user-interface, mson

Amazing work as gone into MSON and it's a great project, however, it appears the backend stores available right now are only firebase, local-storage and memory.

It would be good to ask if someone has successfully used MSON with a GraphQL or a regular RESTful endpoint.

*This should have been directed to @redgeoff himself but it's really hard to tweet to him as his account seem suspended.*

Answer (score 0):

Redgeoff here. I just found this while randomly searching Google. I've been working on a backend layer, that uses GraphQL, which gets auto generated by MSON. At this point, I'm not planning on releasing this layer as open source, but it will be offered at a very reasonable price. If you are interested, please follow me at my new Twitter handle @CoxGeoffrey. The service will be hosted at mson.co